# How do you create a column in MySQL whose value is calculated from the values of other columns

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Emp_Data(
Emp_Id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Emp_FName varchar(20),
Emp_LName varchar(20),
Sales_April NUMERIC(7,2),
Sales_May NUMERIC(7,2),
Sales_June NUMERIC(7,2),
Sales_Total NUMERIC(7,2))
```

I want Sales_Total to be the sum of Sales_April, Sales_May, Sales_June. For this I created:

```
CREATE VIEW `total_view` AS
SELECT `Sales_April`, `Sales_May`, `Sales_June`, `Sales_April + Sales_May + Sales_June`  AS `Sales_Total`
FROM `Emp_Data` ;
```

Apparently, the IDE I use (DBeaver) doesn't support this feature yet. Is creating a trigger a suitable way to go about this? If yes, how will you create a suitable trigger for this?

Comment: `Sales_April + Sales_May + Sales_June` - lose the backticks  or enclose individual columns in backticks Also you have  3 things mention a generated column a trigger and a view  - which do you want? personally I would not store the total and caclulate as and when required..

Comment: MySQL 5.7 and later has a feature of Generated Columns which are exactly what you asking for. Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html I don't use DBeaver, so I don't know if this feature is supported by DBeaver.

Answer (score 0):

given your table above, you already created `sales_total` column. So what is left to do is to `Alter` you table and modify its column like this:

```
Alter table Emp_Data Modify Column Sales_Total Decimal(11,2) as (`Sales_April` + `Sales_May` + `Sales_June`) STORED;
```

Here I use decimal data type for the `Sales_Total` column because in mysql, Numeric is considered as decimal data type.

Comment: 'Numeric data type.; - Yes there is - but it's called decimal see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/other-vendor-data-types.html

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks. will edit this to decimal instead of double.